# Can't position buttons in tkinter in desired area

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is the output screen:

[image: Output Screen]

I want to position Button 5 and 6 in the center of their respective rows, i.e., aligned to Button 1 and Button 2 vertically.

Also, I want to reduce the gap between buttons 3 and 4 but when I try, the whole window changes, even after placing those buttons in separate frames.

Here is the Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

def something():
    pass

def date_entry(frame):
    top = tk.Toplevel(frame)
    ttk.Label(top, text='Choose date').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    cal = DateEntry(top, width=12, background='darkblue',
                    foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

def Home():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('550x400')
    root.title('tkinter')
    root.config(bg = '#f4f5db')

    u_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    u_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0)

    headingLabel =  tk.Label(u_frame, text = ' Heading ', font='candara 30 bold',compound='left',bg='#f4f5db'  )
    headingLabel.grid(row = 0,column= 0)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    u1_frame = tk.Frame(root,bg = '#f4f5db')
    u1_frame.grid(row=1, column = 0 )
    dateLabel = tk.Label(u1_frame, text = ' Date ', font = 'candara 14', bg = '#f7f7e8' ).grid(row =1, sticky = 'w')
    tk.Button(u1_frame, text='DateEntry', command= lambda: date_entry(u1_frame) , relief = 'sunken').grid(row=1,column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    
    Label1 = tk.Label(u1_frame, text = 'Label 1', font = 'candara 14', bg = '#f7f7e8' ).grid(row =2,column = 0)
    Entry1 = tk.Entry(u1_frame, font = 'candara 12').grid(row = 2,column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    Button1 = tk.Button(u1_frame, text = 'Button1', command = something, font = 'candara 12', bg = 'white').grid(row = 3, column = 1)    

    label2 = tk.Label(u1_frame, text = 'label2 : ' , font = 'candara 14' , bg = '#f7f7e8').grid(row = 4, column =0)
    button2 = tk.Button(u1_frame, text = 'Button2', font = 'candara 12', bg = '#f7f7e8').grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    lowerFrame = tk.Frame(root , bg = 'white' ).grid(row = 5, column = 0)
    button3 = tk.Button(lowerFrame , text = 'Button3' , font = 'candara 12' , bg = '#f7f7e8' ).grid(row = 5, column = 0,sticky = 'w', padx = 20, pady = 10)
    button4 = tk.Button(lowerFrame, text = 'Button4', font = 'candara 12' , bg = '#f7f7e8').grid(row = 5, column = 1 , padx = 20, pady = 10)

    lowestFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'white').grid(row = 6, column = 0)
    Button5 = tk.Button(lowestFrame, text = 'Button5',font = 'candara 12' , bg = '#f7f7e8' ).grid(row = 6, column = 1, padx = 20, pady = 10)
    button6 = tk.Button(lowestFrame,text = 'Button6', font = 'candara 12' ,bg = '#f7f7e8' ).grid(row=7, column = 1,  padx = 20, pady = 10)

    root.mainloop()

Home()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used frames correctly in your code, but the positioning needs a bit of work.
When you create a frame, the positioning of the widgets (buttons, labels, frames) in the frame is separate from the frame's parent. This allows you to do useful stuff like use pack in one frame and grid in another.
In your code, you create `u1_frame` as a child of the root window. You then make some labels and buttons as children of `u1_frame`. The label and buttons in the frame (widgets) are not affected by the positioning of the root window, so you can treat it like an empty window and start with row/column 0.
 Later on, you create `lowerFrame` as a child of the root window. The root window currently has 2 widgets in it, `u_frame` and `u1_frame`. Because the positioning of the widgets in the frames don't affect the root window, the row number will be 2 instead of 5 and `lowestFrame` will be row 3 instead of 6. This also means the widgets in `lowerFrame` should be row 0 instead of row 5, as they are in a frame and are not affected by the positioning of the root window widgets. The same applies to `lowestFrame`, the rows should be 0 and 1 for the two buttons.
Now the frames are positioned correctly, we can use `columnspan` to align the buttons as you describe in the question. `columnspan` tells Tkinter how many grid columns you want a widget to take up. By adding `columnspan = 2` to `button5` and `button6`, they will now take up both columns and will, by default, centre themselves in the two columns, which will give the positioning you want.
Because the frames are now positioned correctly, button 3 and 4 should now be in the right place as well. Another thing I would strongly recommend is defining a widget on one line and then placing it on the next. This allows you to refer to the widget later on if you need to change the text or get the value of an entry, for example.
Here is the fixed code:

```
    u_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    u_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    

    headingLabel =  tk.Label(u_frame, text = ' Heading ', font='candara 30 bold',compound='left',bg='#f4f5db'  )
    headingLabel.grid(row = 0,column= 0)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    u1_frame = tk.Frame(root,bg = '#f4f5db')
    u1_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    dateLabel = tk.Label(u1_frame, text = ' Date ', font = 'candara 14', bg = '#f7f7e8' )
    dateLabel.grid(row =0, column = 0, sticky = 'w')
    tk.Button(u1_frame, text='DateEntry', command= lambda: date_entry(u1_frame) , relief = 'sunken').grid(row=0, column = 1, padx=10, pady=10)
    
    Label1 = tk.Label(u1_frame, text = 'Label 1', font = 'candara 14', bg = '#f7f7e8' )
    Label1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    Entry1 = tk.Entry(u1_frame, font = 'candara 12')
    Entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    Button1 = tk.Button(u1_frame, text = 'Button1', command = something, font = 'candara 12', bg = 'white')
    Button1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2)    

    label2 = tk.Label(u1_frame, text = 'label2 : ' , font = 'candara 14' , bg = '#f7f7e8')
    label2.grid(row = 3, column =0)
    button2 = tk.Button(u1_frame, text = 'Button2', font = 'candara 12', bg = '#f7f7e8')
    button2.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    lowerFrame = tk.Frame(root , bg = 'white' )
    lowerFrame.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    button3 = tk.Button(lowerFrame , text = 'Button3' , font = 'candara 12' , bg = '#f7f7e8' )
    button3.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 10)
    button4 = tk.Button(lowerFrame, text = 'Button4', font = 'candara 12' , bg = '#f7f7e8')
    button4.grid(row = 0, column = 1 , padx = 20, pady = 10)

    lowestFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'white')
    lowestFrame.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    button5 = tk.Button(lowestFrame, text = 'Button5',font = 'candara 12' , bg = '#f7f7e8' )
    button5.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 20, pady = 10)
    button6 = tk.Button(lowestFrame,text = 'Button6', font = 'candara 12' ,bg = '#f7f7e8' )
    button6.grid(row=1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 20, pady = 10)
    root.mainloop()
```